# Create Custom/Gif keyboard and add to android system like Tenor does for Gif sharing with system-wide keyboard

Tags: android, android-keypad, android-custom-keyboard

I had created an app which lists and search for GIF images, I want to integrate it with Android System Keyboard, like on keyboard we have options to change between "Google Keyboard", "Indic Keyboard", "Tenor GIF Keyboard" etc. I want my app to work same like those keyboards.

How can I create my app to work like a keyboard and how to add that to system-wide keyboard?

For Example: If we use Tenor Gif Keyboard, whenever we want to send GIF to someone, we switch to Tenor Keyboard and send.

I had referred all other Stack Overflow answers and blogs related to this but no answer is that convincing or useful for the requirement.

Thanks!!